# Port number retrieval

Tags: c#

For port number testing purpose I am passing the following URL, but it throws an exception, exception itself is null - no descriptive information

```
testURL = "ce-34-54-33.compute-1.amazonaws.com:";

Regex r = new Regex(@"^(?<proto>\w+)://[^/]+?:(?<port>\d+)?/",
RegexOptions.None, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(150));
// the following throws an exception
int port = Int32.Parse(r.Match(testURL).Result("${port}"));
```

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

If I use `System.Uri`, the value always -1 no matter whether or not I include port.

```
Uri uri = new Uri(connectionURL);
int value = uri.Port;
```

Comment: It throws an exception but the value of the exception is null? Are you sure? Is it being thrown by `new Regex`, `Match`, `Result`, or `Parse`?

Comment: The last line throws an exception

Comment: The last line has 3 method calls in it. Which one is throwing the exception?

Comment: `"${port}"` looks strange, isn't it a *typo* - `$"{port}"`?

Comment: Please check screenshots, added

Comment: Throws *what* exception? Please create an [mcve]

Comment: Why not use `System.Uri`?

Comment: @Sayse, I am not sure you have read the question carefully.

Comment: Screenshot doesn't show `null`. Maybe you get better result by manually catching?

Comment: Please create an [mcve].

Comment: I strongly believe what I have delivered is more than enough for SFO requirements.

Comment: @Chet, please see my update

Comment: @hotspring however you didn't answer Adrian, Dmitry Bychenko or my comment. You still didn't state at all what is causing the error nor do you want to find out what error, nor do you proof Dmitry that you're wrong or right.

Comment: Dimitri has added his comment as an answer and deleted, because it does not work.

Comment: If you check screenshot carefully, you will see issue of causing null (unable to evaluate the expression), but have no idea how to handle or what is causing this issue.If you have any idea, please provide.

Comment: `testURL = "ce-34-54-33.compute-1.amazonaws.com:"` is it worth an answer that you forgot the `;`?

Comment: of course not :-), you cannot even compile the code, it is an error not exception!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception you get is:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Result cannot be called on a failed Match.'

Your testURL doesn't contain a port, so the named group "port" didn't match anything. It also doesn't contain a "proto", which isn't marked optional, so the entire regex has no matches. Finally, it doesn't end in the required slash.

So fix your input:

```
var testURL = "https://ce-34-54-33.compute-1.amazonaws.com:443/";

Regex r = new Regex(@"^(?<proto>\w+)://[^/]+?:(?<port>\d+)?/");

var port = int.Parse(r.Match(testURL).Result("${port}"));
```

And you'll see it works just fine.

Of course this code still needs additional error handling:

```
var testURL = "https://ce-34-54-33.compute-1.amazonaws.com:443/";

Regex r = new Regex(@"^(?<proto>\w+)://[^/]+?:(?<port>\d+)?/");

var match = r.Match(testURL);

var portGroup = match.Groups["port"];
int port = -1;

if (portGroup.Success)
{
    if (!int.TryParse(portGroup.Value, out port))
    {
        port = -1;
    }
}
```

This sets the port to -1 if none is present in the input URL.

Comment: `var testURL = "https://ce-34-54-33.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8` does not pick up the right port number, it still returns `{}`

Comment: That's because the URL must end in a slash, as dictated by your regex.

Comment: Any idea for the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022396/url-well-formed-returns-true-for-invalid-url